# [osmdroid]Polylines are incompatible

Tags: android, android-studio, osmdroid

`Polyline roadOverlay = RoadManager.buildRoadOverlay(road, Color.RED, 5);` errors because it is incompatible. My Polyline import is `org.osmdroid.api.Polyline;` but it needs to be `import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.Polyline;` . It's all in the versioning but i don't know what version to download. My library versions are

> osmbonuspack_v6.0
>   
> osmdroid-android-5.0
>   
> slf4j-android-1.7.21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it really it's because of the version. Osmdroid-android should be 5.2 and above. The version of 5.2 will be downloaded [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.osmdroid/osmdroid-android/5.2).